# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: value.isUTC is not a function

Tags: javascript, next.js13

When i set value prop to Datepicker it throws an exception that value.isUTC is not a function can anyone help me out?

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                                <DemoContainer components={['DatePicker']}>
                                    <DatePicker
                                        value={selectedDate.endDate ? new Date(selectedDate.endDate) : null}
                                        views={['year', 'month', 'day']}
                                        label='SELECT DATE'
                                        slotProps={{
                                            inputAdornment: {
                                                position: 'start'
                                            },
                                            textField: { size: 'small' }
                                        }}
                                        sx={classes.datePicker}
                                        onChange={(value: Date | null) => handleDateChange(value, 'endDate')}
                                    />
                                </DemoContainer>
                            </LocalizationProvider>
```